# Find node when traversing tree

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures, tree

I want to implement a method that will enable me to find a node in a tree. The way I do it is recursively using global variables to know when to stop.

**I have the class:**

```
class Node    // represents a node in the tree
{ 
     // constructor
     public Node() {
          Children = new List<Node>();
     }

     public List<Node> Children; 
     public string Name;
     public string Content;            
}
```

**And the method I have right now is:**

```
    private bool IsNodeFound = false; // global variable that I use to decide when to stop

    // method to find a particular node in the tree
    private void Find(Node node, string stringToFind, Action<Node> foundNode)
    {
        if(IsNodeFound)
           return;

        if (node.Content.Contains(stringToFind)){
            foundNode(node); 
            IsNodeFound =true;               
        }

        foreach (var child in node.Children)
        {
            if (child.Content.Contains(stringToFind)){
                foundNode(node);
                IsNodeFound =true;               
            }

            Find(child, stringToFind, foundNode);
        }

    }
```

**and the way I use the Find method is like:**

```
   // root is a node that contain children and those children also contain children
   // root is the "root" of the tree
   IsNodeFound =false;
   Node nodeToFind = null;
   Find(root, "some string to look for", (x)=> nodeToFind=x);
```

**So my question is** how can I make this method more elegant. I will like the signature of the method to look like:

```
   public Node FindNode(Node rootNode);
```

I think it is to redundant what am I doing and there is probably a better way of creating that method. Or perhaps I could alter the Node class so that I can achieve the same thing with a linq query.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would do it this way:

Write an instance method to generate a subtree of a node (you could make it an extension if you don't control the `Node` class):

```
public IEnumerable<Node> GetNodeAndDescendants() // Note that this method is lazy
{
     return new[] { this }
            .Concat(Children.SelectMany(child => child.GetNodeAndDescendants()));    
}
```

Then you can just find nodes with a little bit of LINQ:

```
var foundNode = rootNode.GetNodeAndDescendants()
                        .FirstOrDefault(node => node.Content.Contains(stringToFind));

if(foundNode != null)
{
    DoSomething(foundNode);
}
```

Comment: +1 It is great cause I can filter based on any criteria such as: `root.GetSubTree().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name=="Foo");` Thanks a lot!

Comment: Such a clean, precise answer.

Answer (score 15):

You can use one of the other answers that use Linq, or you can use a depth-first search mechanism using recursion:

```
public Node Find(string stringToFind)
{
    // find the string, starting with the current instance
    return Find(this, stringToFind);
}

// Search for a string in the specified node and all of its children
public Node Find(Node node, string stringToFind)
{
    if (node.Content.Contains(stringToFind))
        return node;

    foreach (var child in node.Children) 
    { 
        var result = Find(child, stringToFind);
        if (result != null)
            return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either use a depth-first search using recursion (no need for a global variable to know when to terminate):

```
Node FindNode1( Node rootNode, string stringToFind ) {
    if( rootNode.Content == stringToFind ) return rootNode;
    foreach( var child in rootNode.Children ) {
        var n = FindNode1( child, stringToFind );
        if( n != null ) return n;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Or, if you wish to avoid recursion, you can accomplish the same thing non-recursively with a stack:

```
Node FindNode2( Node rootNode, string stringToFind ) {
    var stack = new Stack<Node>( new[] { rootNode } );
    while( stack.Any() ) {
        var n = stack.Pop();
        if( n.Content == stringToFind ) return n;
        foreach( var child in n.Children ) stack.Push( child );
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the linq answers confuse you as much as me, here's how I would do it with simple recursion.  Note it's depth first, you might want to change it to breadth first if that makes more sense for your model.

```
public Node FindNode(Node rootNode)
{
    if (rootNode.Content.Contains(stringToFind))
       return rootNode;

    foreach (Node node in rootNode.Children)
    {
        if (node.Content.Contains(stringToFind))
           return node;
        else
           return FindNode(node);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't agree more. While there are many cases LINQ-based solutions are beautiful, simplify the code and make its intent really clear, I believe this one is the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion, and  PLinq

```
    private Node Find(Node node, Func<Node, bool> predicate)
    {
        if (predicate(node))
            return node;

        foreach (var n in node.Children.AsParallel())
        {
            var found = Find(n, predicate);
            if (found != default(Node))
                return found;
        }
        return default(Node);
    }
```

And calling code:

```
     var found = Find(root, (n) => n.Content.Contains("3"));
     if (found != default(Node))
         Console.Write("found '{0}'", found.Name);
     else Console.Write("not found");
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider making LINQ-like API: split "Find" and "Act" parts to make it simple. You may not even need any special custom code for "Act" part, existing LINQ will do.

```
public IEnumerable<Node> Where(Func<Node, bool> condition);
```

Depending on your needs you may either walk whole tree once and check each node to implement Where, or do it properly with lazy iteration. For lazy iteration you'll need some sort of structure which remembers current position (i.e. stack of nodes to visit and index of child).

Note: please avoid using global variables. I.e. in your current code simply returning true/false from Find function and stopping iteration when true is returned would be better approach.